# How can I use condition statement and loop in caph template?

Tags: tizen-web-app, caph-framework

I want to use condition statement and loop with in caph template.

Here is caph list:-

```
$('.search_list').caphList({
                    items : results.results,
                    direction: "vertical",
                    template: "searchResults",
                    containerClass : 'category-box',
                    loop: true
                });
```

This is my template code:-

```
<script id="searchResults" type="text/template">
{{if (item.id == '123')}} {{else}} {{/if}}
    <div focusable data-focusable-depth="2" data-focusable-initial-focus="<%=(index===0)?true:false%>">
        <div class="line"><img src="/images/blue_line.png" /></div>
        <div class="search_result_listbox">
            <div class="search_result_img"><img src="<%= item.poster_image.url %>"></div>
                <div class="search_datetime">
                    <p class="search_time"><%= item.media.duration %></p>
                    <p class="search_date"><%= item.updated %></p>
                </div>
            <div class="search_result_para">
                <h3><%= item.title %></h3>
                <p><%= item.summary %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The error which I got when try to use If/else:-

```
Function.ga.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at ga.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at ga.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ga [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at f (caph-jquery.min.js:19)
    at new j (caph-jquery.min.js:19)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (caph-jquery.min.js:19)
```

Comment: What are your conditions? I mean, it is not clear which code you want to be run if item.id is 123. As a general answer, yes, you can use conditional statements in templates.

Comment: When I used the conditional statement then it throws error which I mentioned above.

Comment: I am not talking about the error. The usage of the conditional statements in the template seems to be pointless. What do want to display if the item.id is 123 and what do you want to display if it is not? If you explain that, I can try to help you.

Comment: I have just given example code which I am trying to run.